Root Cause Analysis - Catastrophic Failure of ULN2803 IC
I have a relay board operated thru Darlington array ULN2803. Both the ICs underwent catastrophic failures. I am looking for explanations about this failure and what can be done to avoid these in future.
Edit 1: This circuit is a bought-out item. The circuit accepts logic inputs from a microcontroller board and has a series of optocouplers which control relays thru a series of Darlington transistor arrays. This board has separate DC power input for providing required voltage for driving relays.


so, your design, or someone else's? If you connected everything correctly and operated the thing within specs, I'd say this looks like a terribly broken design, probably, and not something you need to worry about in other contexts.

We don't know the schematics of the device, or how how it is supposed to be used, or how you connected it to anywhere like supplies and control signals. If you want to analyze why it failed, you first need to understand what you were doing when it failed and then analyze why it might have failed if you connected it in some way that caused it to fail.

These kind of parts have a bad reputation for use in industrial applications, going poof is their normal state of affairs. There's not enough info to tell what happened in this specific case.

Closed while I was typing an answer. Again.

@GodJihyo Which makes one curious what made you think the question is answerable, beyond providing various subjective speculations?

@GodJihyo - Hi, As you were writing an answer, I guess you disagree with the community (currently 3 members) voting for closure. If so, remember that you (or any other site member with at least 3000 rep) can vote to reopen the question. There is also more information here: "What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?". || Should the OP be asked to give more info about usage at the time of the failures? And whether they were simultaneous etc. || Someone could ask & self-answer a more general question.

The "Edit1" is rather useless for determining what went wrong. It simply describes what the device is (and it was already apparent from google image search what it is). The needed piece of info is how you tried to use it, i.e. what supply voltages, and relay control signals you wired there, from where, and how. Including any wiring errors made, not simply how you think it was wired. And how was this board and the controlling board powered - was there e.g. an unisolated mains supply involved somewhere?

Looks like the relay supply ended up with mains voltage across it, or possibly reversed voltage at high fault current. User error. I wouldn't be surprised to see damaged traces as well.
This is a very simple circuit- just some optoisolators driving inputs of the ULN2803 which drives relays. Not much to go wrong, at least insofar as to blow the **** out of both those ICs.

A quite hefty mishap; wrong level voltage input or draw.

@Hannu Unsubtle fault.

I'm not a native English speaker, so that comment does not pass as understandable.

I don't really see how you can come to this conclusion with the little information given. Viewing the traces underneath they relays and spotting signs of nasty creepage from contacts to the coils would prove your theory though.

I have long experience with examining and fault finding - to me this looks similar to AC voltage input on a DC circuit. You won't get craters in IC:s easily without that.

Usually getting 230VAC inside the 24VDC parts turns a significant part of the PCBA into charcoal, with traces and ICs etc burnt to crisp. Here it is just the Darlingtons that have popped. Could as well be EMF spikes or some such causing that.

@Lundin To blow the cr_p out of both those ICs simultaneously- the only way I can think of is to do something to the power supply bus which is the only thing the two have in common. The ULN2803 is rated for 50V so it can probably typically take 60 or 70. So more than that, at substantial fault current or reverse voltage at high fault current. I doubt -5V would result in as dramatic craters but I could be wrong on that if it was connected to a PC power supply.

@Lundin Not in 1000 years will EMI blow the tops off those ICs.

That might depend a bit on the length of the mishap, I'd say you're right if it is a (at least semi-)permanent state.

@Hannu The cratered chips point to a sudden and violent demise, rather than a slow cooking. For example, a mains wire brushing against the wrong place with a ground on the other side.

My hands-on experience of using darlingtons is that they pop from reverse EMF, they pop from output mishaps such as shorts or reverse voltage and they pop if you cough or stare intently at them. Why they were phased out of professional industrial applications some 20+ years ago.

Yes, absolutely a sudden mishap, e.g. content on the chip gets into gaseous state quickly.

@Lundin News to me. LCSC has literally millions in stock (eg. ULN2003). I've always found them extremely reliable as display and relay drivers in industrial applications. A bit too high voltage drop for reliable 5V industrial relay driver applications , but they're fine at 12V and 24V.

My experience is that they pop like popcorns if used in any form of mobile/heavy machinery, or in traditional industry environments such as steel mills etc. They are decent to use in parts of the PCB which is never exposed to the outside world (which relay drivers realistically shouldn't be)

@Lundin I have had to fix some less favorable experiences with the DMOS TPICxxx units- power shift registers .. they need careful care and feeding. And the actual small-print reliable output current of the Darlingtons with all outputs 'on' is much, much lower (more like 50-75mA) than the big print datasheet number (500mA). Thermally limited because of the high voltage drop of the Darlington configuration.

I have checked with a ULN2803 and it blows up like this if you connect just about any two pins to 240V mains. I don't think there's much more to it. Of course some other kind of transient could do it, but it all amounts to connecting it to high voltage. I have never blown a Darlington except now and when I would just plainly overload them in a breadboard mishap.
